# Java action listener question

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener

I am creating a custom JPanel element (a login form).

I want to allow people who use my panel to subscribe/listen to an event called "loginSuccessful".

What is the best way to implement this in my JPanel object?

UPDATE: oh and i also want to add that when that action is triggered, i also want to return a "User" object containing the person that was just logged in

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I normally prefer EventBus for those kinds of Events.

Library and Examples can be found [here](https://eventbus.dev.java.net/)

Moreover you should consider to keep businesslogic out of your viewclass (panel) and create some kind of LoginController for your loginbusinesslogic. There are plenty of good examples out there.

EDIT: You can send an UserObject within an EventBusEvent as well.

Comment: Thanks for the link, I didn't know about the EventBus and it may prove to be just what I needed right about now.

Answer (score 0):

I would start by separating your code form widget code. Don't extend where you don't need to. Where classes are focussed on a particular job, everything becomes so much easier.